# Android - Create footer / ticker text to indicate an incoming action on the UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, footer

I am creating a chat client on the Android phone, and when someone messages in through another client the application currently switches over to messenger mode. When someone message in through another client I would like the application to indicate the number of messages and indicate a number to display number of incoming messages. I have seen this UI mechanism used in many different apps and would like to implement it. I have looked all through the Android documentation, but cannot find anything.

Can someone please explain how to place the ticker-text / footer indicator onto the application, or what api I should be using?

Comment: Might help if you post a link to some screenshots of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the applications use 2 methods to notify the user.

The most used is the Notification that display a message on the status bar and if you "open" the status bar it shows the notifications and the user can click on the Notification and open the application.

The other is a Toast, that's a text message that appears on screen, normally on the bottom, that disappears after some time.

I couldn't understand what you want, but these can help you further search for what you want to do.